# How to integrate admob with google play services?

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, admob, google-play-services

Can anyone please tell me how to integrate admob plugin with google play services plug in unity.I am struggle since long time to solve this problem .But, I am not able to solve it.

Comment: Im using Unity Ads which is really simple to use [Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LFF4S9IYKM)

Comment: does is support both Google play services and admob?

Comment: And thank you for your reply

Comment: Im not really sure with admob. Unity provides ads itself so ads showen will by provided by Unity. Its basicly same as admob. Google play services can be implemented in project a different way [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np3Vei9ROog) . I think you can also use admob I think its more complicated. I used Admob in previous project and it was pain to set up.

Comment: its really very complicated.I tried my best but not able to do.

Comment: I have downloaded a plugin(google-services-plugin) it supports ads as well as google play services.(its only shows the login part of playstore but the leaderboard, achievements are not working)

Comment: I have sorted some info in answer. About google-services, I recomend to read docs or atleast watch the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np3Vei9ROog) . It is also pretty simple to set up. But I have never used its ads in unity.

Comment: Sir event this video i have watched.The problem is when i use admob and google play services together it is throwing some error like commondInvocation and cannot repack

Comment: you mean "google play games services", right? these are the services for leaderboards, achievements, quests, multiplayer, etc

Comment: yes(google play services with ads)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Unity Ads and I have been more than satisfied with it. Unity provides ads so if you use their service, ads showen will be provided by Unity. It is very simple to implement. Really good explained in this video [Ads tutorial unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LFF4S9IYKM).
You can show ad just with `Advertisement.Show()` which will show default ad which can be set [here](https://unityads.unity3d.com).

Comment: https://github.com/unity-plugins/google-services-unity (i am using this plugin and i am trying to use ads as well as leaderboard and achievements but when i click the leaderboards button nothing happens and even no errors as well)

Comment: well I can not really help with that. I do not know the error it is showing. Be sure to have everything set correctly. Its important to read docs or atleast watch some tutorials. I have found one [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khlROw-PfNE) . Please also provide the error throwen.

Answer (score 0):

You could start using the [AdMob for Unity](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start).

> The Google Mobile Ads SDK is the latest generation in Google mobile advertising featuring refined ad formats and streamlined APIs for access to mobile ad networks and advertising solutions. The SDK enables mobile app developers to maximize their monetization in native mobile apps.
>
> This repository contains the source code for the Google Mobile Ads Unity plugin. This plugin enables Unity developers to easily serve Google Mobile Ads on Android and iOS apps without having to write Java or Objective-C code. The plugin provides a C# interface for requesting ads that is used by C# scripts in your Unity project.

As stated in the [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830426/5995040), Google has official support for AdMob on Unity game engine and this is the GitHub for [Google Mobile Ads Unity plugin](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/).

Hope this helps.